# JOML : Perspective Matrix doesnot retain shape

Tags: math, opengl, lwjgl, joml

Im trying to make my own 3D engine using LWJGL.
This is the Line of Code which creates the projection matrix for the uniform to pass.
`pMatrix = new Matrix4f().ortho(-2f, 2f, -1.125f, 1.125f, 0.1f, 1000f);`
[Perfectly working Orthographic Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAW2A.png)
**Notice how the rendered mesh is square, correct according to the vertices**
Only changing this one line to 
`pMatrix = new Matrix4f().perspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), 640/360,0.1f, 1000f);`
Breaks It 
[Not Properly working Perspective projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC9sJ.png)

**Notice how in the second image , the mesh is not square**

 Is there something that im doing wrong. If yes , please help me fix it. If not then why is this happening.

Comment: What about `640.0/360.0`? (instead of `640/360`)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes that fixes it. Would love to know y

Comment: _640/360_ is an integral division. The result is an int not a float. So the result is 1.